# Code for arduino help for beginner

Tags: arduino

This is my code and I,m trying to put in a run on timer......., when my digital write 4 comes on it will go off when its greater than 2.5v and my program continues on....but I,m trying to put in the timer if it doesn,t hit that threshold 2.5v in 5 mins it will shut my digital write 4 off and another digital write 6 off

```
if (analogValue < threshold2){  //less 2volts
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH) ;             //compressor on
} 
if (analogValue > threshold3){          //greater than 2.5 volts
    digitalWrite(4,LOW) ;                   // compressor off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an unsigned long that will store a timing value "startMillis" and use this block of code.

```
//drops below threshold
if (analogValue < threshold2){ 
    //turn compressor on and start timing value
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH) ;
    startMillis = millis();

    //the block below will break if either the
    //voltage goes over the threshold or if
    //the timer variable is greater than
    //300,000ms (5min)
    //additionally, if the timer is tripped it will
    //stop channel 6 before breaking
    while ( analogValue < threshold3 ) {
        if ( millis() - startMillis > 300000 ) {
            digitalWrite(6,LOW) ;
            break;
        }
    }

    //after either condition breaks but before
    //exiting the if() code
    digitalWrite(4,LOW) ;
}
```

Comment: This is my full code...... its still freezing if I,m under threshold2,its a system that compresses air up to threshold 3 and then switches off and if it goes below threshold 2 its puts compressed air back in,i just wanted the timer to count up if theres an air leak and it does compress air within 5 mins there be a fault which will shut down my digital read 4 and 6